# How to use a second column to sort if first column show equal values

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a table that shows teams standings.

[image]

Now currently we are using jQuery to sort based on points -> "PTS"
However there are cases like the image above where the points are equal (like the two last teams) in this case to see who should go first we must look at the F column and in this case "Dubai Stallions" should go above the "Abu Dhabi Capitals".

Our code is currently like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.standing table>tbody > tr:not(:first-child)').sort(function (a, b) {
            return +$('td:eq(5)', b).text() > +$('td:eq(5)', a).text();
        }).appendTo('tbody');
    });
</script>
```

and we have for the table

```
<div class="standing">
    <table class="uppercased">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:26%">teams</th>
            <th style="width:6%">gp</th>
            <th style="width:6%">w</th>
            <th style="width:6%">l</th>
            <th style="width:6%">t</th>
            <th style="width:6%">pts</th>
            <th style="width:6%">f</th>
            <th style="width:6%">a</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Standing</th>
            <th style="width:8%">strk</th>
        </tr>
```

With similar  below it.
Can anyone help with adjusting the jQuery?

URL: https://www.eafl.ae/standing?division=varsity

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `if` condition. If points are equal, use the *f* column to sort.

Here is a snippet.

```js
$(function() {

  $('div.standing table>tbody > tr:not(:first-child)').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (+$('td:eq(5)', b).text() != +$('td:eq(5)', a).text()) // Check if PTS column is not equal
      return +$('td:eq(5)', b).text() > +$('td:eq(5)', a).text(); // Use PTS column since they are not equal
    else
      return +$('td:eq(6)', b).text() > +$('td:eq(6)', a).text(); // Sincne PTS column are equal, use the f column

  }).appendTo('tbody');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="standing">
  <table class="uppercased">
    <tr>
      <th style="width:26%">teams</th>
      <th style="width:6%">gp</th>
      <th style="width:6%">w</th>
      <th style="width:6%">l</th>
      <th style="width:6%">t</th>
      <th style="width:6%">pts</th>
      <th style="width:6%">f</th>
      <th style="width:6%">a</th>
      <th style="width:8%">Standing</th>
      <th style="width:8%">strk</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:26%">Team 1</td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%">3</td>
      <td style="width:6%">7</td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:8%"></td>
      <td style="width:8%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:26%">Team 1</td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%">12</td>
      <td style="width:6%">86</td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:8%"></td>
      <td style="width:8%"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:26%">Team 1</td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:6%">3</td>
      <td style="width:6%">33</td>
      <td style="width:6%"></td>
      <td style="width:8%"></td>
      <td style="width:8%"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to help :)